# How do you calculate the total power developed in a circuit?

Tags: power, schematics, diagram

The figure below shows a circuit with 6 elements [image: The circuit diagram]

This table show the values for the currents and voltages in the circuit. [image: A table with current and voltage values]

While it's clear that you need to sum the power dissipated for a subset of the elements, it is unclear to me which elements are dissipating power.

Could someone please tell me how to calculate the total power developed in the circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each element, compare the sign of the voltage to the sign of the current. Or, multiply the current by the voltage and look at the sign of the resulting power value.

- If the current is flowing from the more positive side to the more negative side, then the element must be removing energy from the circuit (dissipating/transducing it, e.g. a resistor, motor, LED).
- If the current is flowing from the more negative side to the more positive side, then the element must be adding energy to the circuit (e.g. a battery or other power supply).

Your diagram is a bit tricky, though: it looks like it uses negative signs to mean "the voltage or current is in the opposite direction as the arrow or plus sign would otherwise indicate". So you've got to read the diagram and change the signs on some of the numbers to get values you can actually compute with.

Ways to check your work:

- You should find that the sum of power from all sources and the sum of power from all sinks is equal. If not, then the circuit is impossible as it violates conservation of energy (or you made a calculation error).
- Apply Kirchhoff's circuit laws. As a special case, note that the currents through elements a, b, and c must be consistent with each other (even if some of them are measured in the opposite direction, which is silly), and the same for e and f.

Comment: His diagram is not tricky. It obeys KVL and KCL with the reference direction shown for the currents (including their sign) and the reference polarity shown for the voltages (including their sign). It's common to get negative values when performing nodal analysis or mesh analysis.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unlike what Kevin Reid said in his answer, the voltages and currents (including their signs and their reference polarity/direction) satisfy Kirchhoff's laws, so they're correct; you don't need to change the sign of anything.

- From Kirchhoff's current law (KCL), an instantaneous current \$i_{\text{a} \to \text{b}}(t)\$ with reference direction pointing from node *a* to node *b* (whether the current \$i_{\text{a} \to \text{b}}\$ is positive or negative) is the negative of the instantaneous  current \$i_{\text{b} \to \text{a}}(t)\$ with reference direction pointing from node *b* to node *a*: \$i_{\text{a} \to \text{b}}(t) = -i_{\text{b} \to \text{a}}(t)\$.

[image]

*Figure 1. Two ways to represent the same current. Image source:* Engineering Circuit Analysis *(8th ed.) by Hayt, Kemmerly and Durbin.*

- From Kirchhoff's voltage law (KVL), an instantaneous voltage \$v_\text{ab}(t)\$ measured at (*i.e.* with positive reference polarity at) node *a* with respect to (w.r.t.) node *b* (whether the voltage \$v_\text{ab}\$ is positive or negative) is the negative of the instantaneous voltage \$v_\text{ba}(t)\$ measured at node *b* w.r.t. node *a*: \$v_\text{ab}(t) = -v_\text{ba}(t)\$.

[image]

*Figure 2. Two ways to represent the same voltage. Image source: textbook by Kemmerly* et al.

---

Let's check the voltages and currents. I'll use the same reference polarity for the voltages and the same reference direction for the currents shown in your diagram, and I'll use the same values (including signs) shown in your table.

Applying KVL around the left mesh in counterclockwise direction starting at the lower left node:

\$ \begin{align} 0 \text{ V} &= - v_\text{a} + v_\text{b} - v_\text{d} + v_\text{c} \\ \implies 0 \text{ V} &= - (+36 \text{ V}) + (-23 \text{ V}) - (-80 \text{ V}) + (-21 \text{ V}) \\ \implies 0 \text{ V} &= 0 \text{ V} \end{align}\$

which is obviously true, so these values are correct.

Applying KVL around the right mesh in counterclockwise direction starting at the lower middle node:

\$ \begin{align} 0 \text{ V} &= + v_\text{d} - v_\text{e} + v_\text{f} \\ \implies 0 \text{ V} &= + (-80 \text{ V}) - (+60 \text{ V}) + (+140 \text{ V}) \\ \implies 0 \text{ V} &= 0 \text{ V} \end{align}\$

which is obviously true, so these values are also correct.

And applying KCL at the upper middle node:

\$ \begin{align} 0 \text{ A} &= + i_\text{b} - i_\text{d} + i_\text{e} \\ \implies 0 \text{ A} &= + (-4 \text{ A}) - (-1.5 \text{ A}) + (+2.5 \text{ A}) \\ \implies 0 \text{ A} &= 0 \text{ A} \end{align}\$

which is obviously true, so these values are also correct.

Thus all values for voltages and currents in the diagram are correct, considering their reference polarity/direction.

---

Secondly, it can be proven that, if the reference direction of the instantaneous conventional current \$i(t)\$ through a two-terminal element and the reference polarity of the instantaneous voltage \$v(t)\$ across the two-terminal element are chosen such that the arrowhead of the current points *towards* the element *into* the *positive* reference terminal (the terminal marked with the "\$+\$" sign), then, the product \$v(t) \, i(t)\$ is the instantaneous power \$p(t)\$ *consumed* by the element. So a positive value for \$p\$ indicates energy flow *into* the element from the external circuit, and a negative value indicates energy flow *out of* the element into the external circuit. This is known as the *[passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention)*. This is shown in the following figure.

[image]

*Figure 3. If the reference polarity for \$v\$ and the reference direction for \$i\$ are as shown in this figure, then \$v \, i\$ is the power *consumed* by the element. Image source: textbook by Kemmerly* et al.

Using the passive sign convention for all elements, the law of conservation of energy (in terms of power) of a lumped isolated circuit can be stated as follows (for a reference, read section 1.5 of *Fundamentals of Electric Circuits* [5th ed.] by Alexander and Sadiku):

\$\displaystyle\sum p_\text{consumed}(t) = 0 \text{ W}\$

In the above equation, a negative value simply means energy delivered/generated/supplied instead of energy consumed/absorbed. This is similar to how in KCL negative values indicate charge flow out of a node instead of into the node.

---

Let's compute the powers. We're going to compute the power *consumed* by each element, whether it is positive (meaning it is really consumed by the element) or it is negative (meaning it is actually generated by the element). So the voltage polarity and current direction for each element must be as shown in figure 3. In your diagram, not all elements satisfy this; elements *b*, *e* and *f* indeed satisfy the passive sign convention, but elements *a*, *c* and *d* don't. So we must first swap either the current reference direction (and change its sign, as shown in figure 1) or the voltage reference polarity (and change its sign, as shown in figure 2) for each element that doesn't satisfy the passive sign convention. I will choose to swap the voltage polarity (and sign), but if you want you could swap the current direction (and sign) instead. After doing this, we get the following diagram.

[image]

*Figure 4.*

Now we can compute the power *consumed* by each element.

- The power consumed by element *a* is \$p_\text{a} = (-v_\text{a})(i_\text{a}) = (-[+36 \text{ V}])(-4 \text{ A}) = +144 \text{ W} \$.
- The power consumed by element *b* is \$p_\text{b} = (v_\text{b})(i_\text{b}) = (-23 \text{ V})(-4 \text{ A}) = +92 \text{ W} \$.
- The power consumed by element *c* is \$p_\text{c} = (-v_\text{c})(i_\text{c}) = (-[-21 \text{ V}])(+4 \text{ A}) = +84 \text{ W} \$.
- The power consumed by element *d* is \$p_\text{d} = (-v_\text{d})(i_\text{d}) = (-[-80 \text{ V}])(-1.5 \text{ A}) = -120 \text{ W} \$. In other words, the power generated by element *d* is \$-p_\
  text{d} = +120 \text{ W} \$.
- The power consumed by element *e* is \$p_\text{e} = (v_\text{e})(i_\text{e}) = (+60 \text{ V})(+2.5 \text{ A}) = +150 \text{ W} \$.
- The power consumed by element *f* is \$p_\text{f} = (v_\text{f})(i_\text{f}) = (+140 \text{ V})(-2.5 \text{ A}) = -350 \text{ W} \$. In other words, the power generated by element *f* is \$-p_\text{f} = +350 \text{ W} \$.

At last we apply the law of conservation of energy (in terms of power):

\$\begin{align} 0 \text{ W} &= p_\text{a} + p_\text{b} + p_\text{c} + p_\text{d} + p_\text{e} + p_\text{f} \\ \implies 0 \text{ W} &= (+144 \text{ W}) + (+92 \text{ W}) + (+84 \text{ W}) + (-120 \text{ W}) + (+150 \text{ W}) + (-350 \text{ W}) \\ 0 \text{ W} &= 0 \text{ W} \end{align} \$

which is obviously true, so these values are correct.

To find the actual total power consumed, sum up all positive consumed powers; and to find the actual total power generated, sum up all negative consumed powers and multiply it by -1; note that this requires to know the numerical sign of each power:

- Actual total power consumed: \$p_\text{a} + p_\text{b} + p_\text{c} + p_\text{e} = (+144 \text{ W}) + (+92 \text{ W}) + (+84 \text{ W}) + (+150 \text{ W}) = +470 \text{ W}\$.
- Actual total power generated: \$-(p_\text{d} + p_\text{f}) = -([-120 \text{ W}] + [-350 \text{ W}]) = +470 \text{ W}\$.